# Ember CLI ES6 Modules: import path to app root

Tags: ember.js, module, ember-cli, ecmascript-6

I find the import path in ES6 modules very confusing when using it in Ember CLI.  For example, if I want to import a model deep in my application, I end up doing something like this:

```
import User from '../../../../../models/user';
```

This is an exercise of trial and error, as it's hard to easily visualize how deep in the folder tree I'm using this from.  Even worse, if I refactor my files, everything breaks.

So alternatively, I can use an absolute path like this:

```
import User from 'app-name/models/user';
```

I prefer not to hard-code the app name into the path, because it can change.

Is there a shorthand to specify the app root?

`./` doesn't work because `./` implies current path.

```
import User from './models/user';
```

Comment: This post has a variety of ideas: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2014/02/20/how-i-work-around-the-require-problem-in-nodejs/

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no way to programmatically name ES6 imports at least in Ember so you can't use `ENV.modulePrefix`.

However there is a workaround. Whenever you want to change module prefix run this GNU sed command from ZSH inside Ember root.

```
sed -i 's/previousName/newName/g' **/*
```